# Is it possible to change the user status on Facebook, using the 'Official PHP Client Library'?

Tags: php, facebook

I downloaded the .php files from [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP), and I am able to take the first and last name or friend names, but now I want to update the status of a user.
I am following the RESTful API documentation, however I can't find a relevant method in the facebookapi_php5_restlib.php file. Am I missing something here, or this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.setStatus

with proper permissions you can use the `users_setStatus()` function to update the user's status.

basic call:

```
$result = $facebook->api_client->users_setStatus($status);
```

you can also use the stream.publish method:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish